# Hibernate: why use O/R mapping?

Tags: hibernate, data-annotations, hibernate-mapping

I'm new to Hibernate.

1) I don't quite understand why we need to specify O/R mapping relationship in *.hbm.xml file or add annotations for "one-to-one", "one-to-many", etc in databeans. Is it a must to have them? How does O/R mapping relationship really work behind the scene?

2) What is the difference between adding relationship to *.hbm.xml and databean annotation? Should we do both? Advantages and disadvantages for each of them?

Comment: FYI I voted to close as this question is just too broad. I will unvote if you can try to be more specific. The `*.hbm.xml` are the legacy way in hibernate of mapping Java POJOs to database entities (usually tables). Now days most users use JPA annotations.

Comment: @AdamGent The main reason why I ask this question is that I don't understand why we need to use relationship annotation when I'm reading through hibernate tutorials online. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_or_mappings.htm Whether it is a must to do so and why.

Comment: @AdamGent It will be great if you can recommend some good docs that can clearly explain why we need this. I can't really see why a direct question like this is too broad?

Comment: I retracted my vote. I misread your question and I have answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.

You do not need the `*.hbm.xml` files. There are plenty of examples on the web using JPA annotations. There are ORM implementations that do not need configuration and will use the database to create classes (particularly in dynamically typed languages) but Hibernate is not one of them.

Hibernate looks at the class and configuration (JPA annotations and/or XML) and see if a entity exists and matches correctly (depending on configuration).

> 2.

The advantage to using the XML is that your domain objects are in theory slightly less coupled but in practice this generally not worth the effort because the annotations (JPA) are decoupled themselves. If the annotations were packaged with Hibernate and proprietary to Hibernate this would be more of an issue. Also some people just don't like annotations.

The huge advantage of using JPA annotations is in *theory* you can switch JPA implementations which is not the case with hibernate XML files. However in practice generally switching JPA implementations midstream is a non trivial task.

Comment: for JPA annotations, do you think I should follow this doc http://www.techferry.com/articles/hibernate-jpa-annotations.html?

Comment: Seems fine to me but I didn't entirely peruse it.